# テキストを標準出力するとテキストの末尾に不要なNoneがついてしまう

Tags: python

このようにコードを入力すると、

```
この投稿はHanakoさんが2020.01.26に投稿しました。None
```

と出ます。このNoneは何ですか？
Noneを消したいのに消せません。

[image]

Comment: 質問対象のソースコードはスクリーンショットへのリンクやスクリーンショットそのものではなく、テキストで提示してください。これらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765)

Comment: `Card.comment()` メソッドには `return` 文がないので `None` が返ります。なので、`def comment(self): return "この投稿は{}さんが{}に投稿しました".format(self.name, self.date)` とするとよいかと。

Comment: あるいは`print(User_a.comment())`の行で`print()`は使わずに単に`User_a.comment()`とすることですね。こちら類似の質問 [pythonでクラス内のprintでnoneがでないように設定したい。](https://teratail.com/questions/148585) ではそれがベストアンサーになっています。

Comment: returnにしたらできました。ちなみに、returnとprintの使い分けがいまいち分かりません。ある方の動画では、同じdefでもprintを使ったcommentの出力方法でしたが、回答者さんが仰るようにreturnで教えてくださる方もいました。結果を後で利用するのがreturnだという解説もありましたが、私の今回のコードの場合、それに該当するのでしょうか？

Comment: その辺は大変興味深い新規質問なので別途挙げていただくと幸い。まあ要するに責任分担の問題ですよ。ある立場で `comment()` 関数の責務は「記事文書を作るところまで」とするなら `return` すべきでしょう。この場合、記事文書を出力するのは `comment()` を呼んだ側の責務になります。別の立場で `comment()` の責務が「記事を出力するまで」とするなら `comment()` の中で `print` すべきでしょう。出力先を変更したくなったときには前者のほうが修正が楽かもしれないですけどね。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます！責任の問題…難しいですね…何となくですがわかったような気がします…！もう少し理解を深めてみようと思います！ありがとうございました！

Comment: SO では自己回答も推奨されていますので、理解できたらご自分で「回答」してみてください。まあオイラが回答してもいいんですけどね